# Let A,B,C be sets. If A△B=A△C, does this imply that B=C?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I believe that a counterexample exists, but I have struggled to find one since I need to satisfy (A\B) U (B\A) = (A\C) U (C\A), which is a very complex statement. Also I used △ to represent symmetric difference.

Comment: Note that $A \triangle B = (A \cup B) - (A\cap B)$  Now it is easy to prove in cases.  If $b \in B$ argue that $b \in C$ by cases $b \in A$ or $b \notin A$.  Repeat the other direction.

Comment: For a more conceptual answer: symmetric difference is a group operation on sets; the identity element is the empty set; and every set is its own inverse. So your question can be regarded as just the left cancellation law for groups.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\Delta$ is associative, hence $A\operatorname{\Delta}B=A\operatorname{\Delta}C$ implies
$$ B=(A\operatorname{\Delta}A)\operatorname{\Delta}B=A\operatorname{\Delta}(A\operatorname{\Delta}B)=A\operatorname{\Delta}(A\operatorname{\Delta}C)=(A\operatorname{\Delta}A)\operatorname{\Delta}C=C.$$

Comment: LOL I love this.  I was trying to avoid the group-theoretic approach, but this is cleaner.

Comment: Yep—my first thought was that $A \mathbin{\Delta} B = A \mathbin{\Delta} C$ gives $(A \mathbin{\Delta} B) \mathbin{\Delta} (A \mathbin{\Delta} C) = \emptyset$, so $(A \mathbin{\Delta} A) \mathbin{\Delta} (B \mathbin{\Delta} C) = \emptyset$, so $B = C$. (This also uses commutativity.)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$, and the equality of symmetric differences holds.

There are two cases:

1. $x\in A$: here you easily see it is not in $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$ but it *is* in $(A\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus A)$, a contradiction
2. $x\notin A$: then it is not in $(A\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus A)$ but it is in $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$, another contradiction.

Therefore no such $x$ exists, and $B\subseteq C$.  By the symmetric argument, $C\subseteq B$.

---

Another algebraic way to do it is if you know that (assuming $A,B,C$ are subsets of $X$) $\triangle$ is an abelian group operation on the subsets of $X$, one in which all elements have order $2$, and the emptyset is the identity.

Suppose we then write $A\triangle B=A+B$. Then the equation $A+B=A+C$ can be simplified by adding $-A=A$ to both sides, whereupon you immediately get $C=B$.

Answer (score 3):

For me, manipulations with $\triangle$ are easier if one uses the characteristic function
noting that $1_{A \triangle B} = 1_A \oplus 1_B$,
where $\oplus$ is 'exclusive or' (mild abuse of notation).

If $x,y$ have values in $\{0,1\}$, then $x \oplus x = 0$, $0 \oplus x = x$.
(Equivalently, $A \triangle A = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \triangle A = A$.)

Using characteristic functions, we have
$1_A \oplus 1_B = 1_A \oplus 1_C$, so $1_A \oplus 1_A \oplus 1_B = 1_{B}$ and similarly 
$1_A \oplus 1_A \oplus 1_C = 1_{C}$. Hence $1_{B} = 1_{C}$ and so $B=C$.

Comment: Corrected egregious mistake.

Answer (score 2):

For an elementary approach, you can split into cases - it's most convenient to make cases based on whether $x\in A$. We want to show that, given that $A\triangle B=A\triangle C$, we have that $x\in B$ if and only if $x\in C$.

So, first let's handle the case where $x\in A$. Note that $x\in A\triangle B$ if and only if $x\not\in B$ and $x\in A\triangle C$ if and only if $x\not\in C$. However, $x\in A\triangle B$ if and only if $x\in A\triangle C$ as these sets are equal, so we find that, if $x\in A$, then $x\not\in B$ if and only if $x\not\in C$. The case where $x\not\in A$ is handled similarly - though if you were trying to write this out very formally, you might split into further cases to avoid confusions from using statement like "if this, then this if and only if that".

A more elegant way to show this would be to show the following identity:
$$A\triangle (A\triangle S) = S.$$
Then, starting from $A\triangle B=A\triangle C$, you can just apply $A\triangle \cdot$ to both sides to get
$$A\triangle (A\triangle B)=A\triangle (A\triangle C)$$
And then use the identity on both sides to get
$$B=C$$

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add one more proof -- by contradiction. Suppose there exist such $x \in B$ that $x \notin C$. Consider two cases
$$
x \in A 
\xrightarrow{x \notin C} x \in A \triangle C
\xrightarrow{A \triangle C = A \triangle B} x \in A \triangle B
\xrightarrow{x \in A} x \notin B
~~~~~~\text{(contradiction)}
$$
$$
x \notin A 
\xrightarrow{x \in B} x \in A \triangle B
\xrightarrow{A \triangle C = A \triangle B} x \in A \triangle C
\xrightarrow{x \notin A} x \in C
~~~~~~\text{(contradiction)}
$$
Swapping letters 'B' and 'C' we can prove that there is also no such $x$ that $x \notin B$ and $x \in C$.
This completes the proof.